# Not able to Stop/Start Windows services without admin CMD

Tags: jenkins, cmd, scripting

When i am starting the service using cmd without administrator mode i am getting access denied error.

[image: cmd without administrator]

But When i am starting the service using cmd as administrator, i am able to do it.
[image: cmd as administrator]

So When i am running the batch file from "Jenkins" the same is failing with "Access is denied " error.

Can i run the job from **jenkins** so that the commands will be executed in admin cmd.

I have heard about the **runas** command. Will this be useful in my scenario.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I am not able to find the process to kill. could you brief, which process can be killed?

Comment: it is an access denied error, meaning you user does not have access to start the system process.

Comment: Ahh... sorry, don't mind me, I mistook it as stop/delete. My apologies.

Comment: Right click Jenkins and choose *Run as Administrator*.

Answer (score 0):

As one of solutions: you can run Jenkins agent (service) under account, which have administrative permissions.

Go to `Services` -> find `Jenkins agent` service -> Right Mouse Click and choose `Properties` -> `Log on` tab -> Specify account with proper permissions.

[image: RunServiceUnderSpecificAccount]